# In this integral possible to do? $\int \frac{\ln(x^2+x+1)}{x^3+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, polynomials, logarithms

I have no idea to where i can aproximate on to this integral

$$\int \frac{\ln(x^2+x+1)}{x^3+1}dx$$

Comment: So this is an integral as an exercise from your textbook?

Comment: Maybe $\frac{\ln(x^2+x+1)}{(x+1)(x^2-x+1)}$ can help in combination with partial fraction decomposition to reduce the problem to other integrals, that are still hard to solve :D.

Comment: What does it mean to 'approximate' and indefinite integral, which results in a(n equivalence class of) functions?  A series expansion?  Or did you mean to have bounds on the integral?

Answer (score 0):

The integral is *possible* to do, but that doesn't mean it is pretty... here is the answer Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica gave me:
[image: Wolfram Alpha Picture]

Comment: In particular this antiderivative uses the polylogarithm $\textrm{Li}_2$, so many readers would not consider this to be a closed-form expression.

Comment: @Travis It is true that many readers would not consider this a closed-form expression, but it does serve to express the complexity of this problem. I consider these expressions to be pseudo-closed-form, which is better than having nothing.

Comment: @Travis You are correct;  some readers would not view this as closed form.  In my humble opinion, I would argue that this is just as closed-form an answer as one that contains the so-called "elementary functions" (e.g., trigonometric, exponential, logarithm) only.  I really don't see the rationale of classifying the sine function, for example, as an acceptable closed-form function, while a Bessel function (or here, the dilogarithm) would be considered "special" and therefore not closed form.   But again, this is my perspective and others vehemently disagree.

Comment: @Dr.MV I have always had the same opinion as you. The sine function was invented to serve our purposes just as bunch as a Bessel function, and I have never understood why we make such a separation. The one function that always annoys me is $\Gamma(x)$. This function pops up everywhere in mathematics, but is considered "special". I feel like we should stop worrying about "elementary" expressions and simply attempt to get the simplest analytic expression.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I certainly did not mean to criticize your solution, or to suggest that it shouldn't be posted. On the contrary, I think it's about the best answer OP could hope for given the problem.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen If a function has been well-studied and has a known series representation, integral representation, values known at specific arguments, has known and useful properties and identities(reflection, inversion, etc.), then it is closed-form.

Comment: @Travis I hope that you didn't take my comment to be offensive or otherwise "negative."  I was merely giving this users humble perspective.  ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV If one accepts the exponential function as "elementary", then immediately $\sin x := \frac{1}{2i}[\exp (ix) - \exp (-ix)]$ is elementary too. The dilogarithm and Bessel functions cannot be so described. I agree that there's generally too much emphasis on what counts as elementary, as this is, modulo the above sorts of implications, ultimately an arbitrary matter of taste.

Comment: Where it does matter practically is exactly this sort of (apparent) setting, where someone who may well be learning integral calculus is grappling with finding an antiderivative of a not-too-unreasonable looking function: A student at that level typically only has exposure to algebraic + exponential + log + trig functions in the first place, so I commented about closed-form-ness just to emphasize that this problem was outside the scope of that skillset.

Comment: @Dr.MV No, I didn't at all; in fact, I think your perspective here is entirely reasonable.

Comment: @Travis I understand completely. My commentary was not intended to downplay the importance of presenting solutions to students on that level in the most elementary form possible; I was simply saying that I feel slightly too much emphasis is given on elementary functions in general. If there is an elementary solution to this problem I feel that we should present that solution, but seeing as their is none I presented one with special functions.

Comment: @Travis I agree with the logic.  If one assumes the exponential to be elementary, then the trig and hyperbolic trig are also.  But how does one define $e^x$?  As a limit, as the inverse of the log, which itself can be defined as an integral, as a series representation, or otherwise, all of which require some limiting operations.  So, it is that sense that this reader stops differentiating (no pun intended .... well, maybe a little bit) one well-studied function from another.  And this sentiment seems aligned with your last sentence.  ;-))

Comment: Students learning integral calculus have more or less universally already encountered exponential functions $x \mapsto a^x$: For $x$ an integer one defines this in terms of multiplication (and inversion of $x < 0$), for $a \geq 0$ and rational $x$, say, $x = p / q$ one can define this as $\sqrt[q]{a^p}$, and then handwave that this makes sense for all real $x$ (which is entirely plausible given a graph). $e$ itself is just a special (if, at that level, only mysteriously distinguished) number...

Comment: @Brevan Ellefsen: I agree with Travis. You said the most simple expression. Why shouldn't we define the integral to be a function for itself. That would be even shorter. But i think the purpose of elementary function is, that we don't define a new function for every new integral that is not that easy to solve.

Comment: ...So, for a typical integral calculus student $e^x$ (and $\sin x$, etc.) are familiar, and hence elementary, in a way $\textrm{Li}_2$ and Bessel functions are not, even if this familiarity is predicated on a chain of ideas that has gaps that students typically don't realize are there until later.